# How can I find the shortest path from A to B on a grid?

Tags: c++, recursion, matrix

In my exercise I need to find the shortest path from one point to another on a matrix, and there are some obstacles in the way. I am using C++ code.

For example:

```
X X X X X X X X

X X X 4 X X 3 X

X X 8 X X X X X

0 X X X X 6 X X
```

If I need to get from the location holding **0** to the location holding **3**, I know that I have to go six steps to the right and two steps up. But, in my exercise I can't pass over another number; the path must only use locations marked by an **X**.

I tried to write a recursive function to solve this problem, but it's not working.

Can anyone please help me?

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
int Rec(Point start, Point finish,Direction dira)
{
    int up = 0, down = 0, left = 0, right = 0;
    int res;
    Point tmp;
    if (finish.getX() == start.getX() && finish.getY()==start.getY())
        return 0;
    else if (dira == UP)
    {
        tmp = start;
        tmp.setY(start.getY() - 1);
        if (screen->getBoardChar(tmp) == ' '){
            up++;
            up += Rec(tmp, finish, UP);
        }       
        tmp = start;
        tmp.setX(start.getX() + 1);
        if (screen->getBoardChar(tmp) == ' '){
            right++;
            right += Rec(tmp, finish, RIGHT);
        }       
        tmp = start;
        tmp.setX(start.getX() - 1);
        if (screen->getBoardChar(tmp) == ' '){
            left += Rec(tmp, finish, LEFT);
            left++;
        }
    }
    else if (dira == DOWN)
    {
        tmp = start;
        tmp.setY(start.getY() + 1);
        if (screen->getBoardChar(tmp) == ' ') {
            down++;
            down += Rec(tmp, finish, DOWN);
        }
        tmp = start;
        tmp.setX(start.getX() + 1);
        if (screen->getBoardChar(tmp) == ' ') {
            right++;
            right += Rec(tmp, finish, RIGHT);
        }
        tmp = start;
        tmp.setX(start.getX() - 1);
        if (screen->getBoardChar(tmp) == ' ') {
            left += Rec(tmp, finish, LEFT);
            left++;
        }
    }
    else if (dira == LEFT)
    {
        tmp = start;
        tmp.setY(start.getY() + 1);
        if (screen->getBoardChar(tmp) == ' ') {
            down++;
            down += Rec(tmp, finish, DOWN);
        }
        tmp = start;
        tmp.setX(start.getX() - 1);
        if (screen->getBoardChar(tmp) == ' ') {
            left += Rec(tmp, finish, LEFT);
            left++;
        }
        tmp = start;
        tmp.setY(start.getY() - 1);
        if (screen->getBoardChar(tmp) == ' ') {
            up++;
            up += Rec(tmp, finish, UP);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        tmp = start;
        tmp.setY(start.getY() + 1);
        if (screen->getBoardChar(tmp) == ' ') {
            down++;
            down += Rec(tmp, finish, DOWN);
        }
        tmp = start;
        tmp.setY(start.getY() - 1);
        if (screen->getBoardChar(tmp) == ' ') {
            up++;
            up += Rec(tmp, finish, UP);
        }
        tmp = start;
        tmp.setX(start.getX() + 1);
        if (screen->getBoardChar(tmp) == ' ') {
            right++;
            right += Rec(tmp, finish, RIGHT);
        }
    }
    res = Smallest(up, down, left, right);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I tried to clarify your title and the text of your question. It would be helpful to know exactly what you mean when you say that your code isn't working.

Comment: Hi, the issue is that the rec dont realy give me to correct number of steps.. i dont know more than ;/

Answer (score 0):

Its easy you have two positions Where you are now , and where you need to go , so you do while loops until you get at right x and then do while loop until you reach right y . you also need to know witch direction to go so you have calculate that too its not hard ether

```
int char[4][8] = { values };
int fromnum;// from witch number
int tonum;// to number 
int fromx, fromy;//from coordinates
int tox,toy; // to coordinates 
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int a = 0; a < 8; a++) {
        //find a cordinates of your start and end point
    }
}

// when you know cordinates you can just supstract them and you will know the path
```